# SQL Server 2012 CPU core usage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Having some trouble figuring out how to alter the core usage on SQL Server 2012 Enterprise. On a server with 16 cores, is there any way to alter which ones will actively use the SQL database, and not on others?

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server Management Studio, rt-click on your instance and select Properties. Then select Processors. Uncheck "Automatically set..." and set CPU affinity how you would like.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using CPU Affinity. This can be controlled by right clicking on the instance, going to properties and then processors.

In this screen, you can set the IO affinity which will control which CPUs/cores that SQL SErver will use.